# close window automatically after capture .aspx page html

Tags: .net

how do i close browser window automatically.I have one page it contains send mail button after clicking i redirect some page and capture whole html content of that page want to send by mail but problem is that after sending mail that page is displayed onto browser window that my requirement is that page not  show onto browser only display send mail or error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript. Add a call to `window.close()` when you're done. Beware, the user will be asked in a prompt.

Comment: This will work only if you have opened a window with window.open command

Comment: hi i have used javascript but its not working i have opene window using window.open but i used render method to capture whole html to send mail and mail will send succesfully but that page viewed into browser

Comment: @Mahadev When you create the window, just hold a reference to it in a variable ej:  var win = window.Open(bla, bla, bla); YourCode(); win.close()

Answer (score 0):

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

Where location is your current window